# Fastest way of loading a large number (600) of large images (42M px) in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I am processing images with OpenCV, and saving these in a Numpy array with `numpy.save`. I find myself with this kind of file: a 600(number of images) x 5248(height) x 7936(width) x 3(channels) .npy file, that weights around 70GB.

I then need in another program to load this file and show the images at a fast pace. If I'm not mistaken, loading a 70GB file regardless of the RAM size is a not viable.

Hence my question, should I save the images in multiple smaller arrays ? And if so, how can I define the right amount of images per array ? As for the loading, should I use multiprocessing or multithreading ?

Also, is there perhaps a better type of file in which to store the images ?

Comment: As a basic instinct I would suggest you to save 600 individual images to different 600 files.

Comment: Sometimes, I use h5py to store matrix representations of images.

Comment: Also while using `numpy.save()` you cannot leverage the Image compression aspect(that's why you seeing such a large size). Try saving the images using `cv2.imwrite()` with either `.jpg`(lossy) or `.png`(lossless) extension

Comment: Or make them into a video maybe?

Comment: @ZdaR Agreed, though 42Mpixel sounds like a high-end DSLR camera, and such photos will likely not work so well as PNG files.